# How to show bottom tab menu on all screens even dont't exist tab with specific screen?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How to show bottom tab menu on all screens even don't exist tab with a specific screen?

```
    const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    MainStack,
    HistoryStack,
  }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator({
      Main: tabNavigator,
      Test:Test,
      Test1: Test1
  },
      {
          initialRouteName: 'Test',
      })
);
```

At the moment Test1, Test screens doesnt show tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a test screen inside the tab navigator stack. The test screen is currently separate within the switch navigator.

- MainStack

  - Test1

```js
    export default createAppContainer(
      createSwitchNavigator({
          Main: tabNavigator
      },
          {
              initialRouteName: 'Main',
          })
    );
```